# If there is a way to asynchronously load a React functional component within same file in react/react-native

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, import, components, lazy-evaluation

We know we cannot use async/await for functional components. An alternate is to conditionally render the component. So, why can't we use async/await for functional components? Or is there a way to lazy load the component defined within the same file without dynamic import?

```
export default function App() {
  // fetch data
  //store data
  // show data
  // add data
  // filter top 5 data based on alphabetical order
  // lazy load component
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://gorest.com/public/v2/users")
      .then((res) => (res.ok ? res.json() : []))
      .then((res) => {
        if (res) {
          setData(res);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value.length > 0 && e.target.value !== " ") {
      setName(e.target.value);
    }
  };
  const addName = () => {
    let newData = [...data];

    let newObject = {};
    if (name.length > 0 && name !== " ") {
      newObject = { name: name, id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) };
      newData.push(newObject);

      // console.log("newData", newData);
      setName("");
      setData(newData);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <input value={name} type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
      <button onClick={addName}>Add Name</button>
      <List array={data} />
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <FilteredComponent array={data} />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
export const FilteredComponent = ({ array }) => {
  let newArray = [...array];
  newArray.sort((a, b) => b.name - a.name);
  newArray = newArray.slice(0, 5);
  return  <List array={newArray} />;
};
```